# Element with fixed position and display table

Tags: html, css

I want to have an element with fixed position relatively to the four sides of the window and with `display:table`.

But if I try to give to my div both the `position:fixed` and `display:table` properties, then the `right` and `bottom` properties are ignored.

I can attain my goal with an additional wrapper :

```
<div id=w>
  <div id=a>
    <div id=b>B</div>
    <div id=c>C</div>
  </div>
</div>

#w {
   position: fixed;
   top: 40px; left:40px; right: 40px; bottom: 40px;
}
#a{
  display: table;
  width:100%; height:100%;
}
#b {
  display: table-row;
  background: red;
  height:40%;
}
#c {
  display: table-row;
  background: yellow;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/EYAXuZo/1/edit)**

But I don't like to have useless divs in my HTML. Is there a way to do it without that `#w` div ? The HTML should be

```
  <div id=a>
    <div id=b>B</div>
    <div id=c>C</div>
  </div>
```

(CSS tricks like `:before` pseudo elements would be fine).

The solution must work on IE9+, Firefox and Chrom(e|ium).

Comment: You can always substitute `body` for that wrapper `div` :P

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn There's a lot of things besides those divs in my real pages.

Comment: Fair enough. As for why this doesn't seem to work unless you use a wrapper, that's because `position` and offsets work differently for tables, even block-level tables. The spec covers this pretty well: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#model If you change `position: fixed` to `position: absolute` while not using a wrapper element, you'll see that scrollbars are generated for an extra 40px of the element's width and height.

Comment: You might want to test on a question that has no comments, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22552338/what-version-of-ie-doesnt-pass-the-event-as-argument-to-listeners - right now I'm getting notified of all your comments as I'm the only other user in this thread.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using `calc()` - I'm not sure it is the best solution (in fact I'm pretty sure it is not, however it works)

[MDN calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)  *([French](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/CSS/calc))*

```
#a { 
   position: fixed;
   display: table;
   height: calc(100% - 80px);
   width: calc(100% - 80px);
   top: 40px; left:40px; right: 40px; bottom: 40px;
}

#b {
  display: table-row;
  background: red;
  height:40%;

}
#c {
  display: table-row;
  background: yellow;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/EYAXuZo/6/edit)

Comment: +1 but... I was hoping it was good but sadly, it doesn't work on IE9 :(

Comment: @dystroy http://caniuse.com/calc you can get 'somewhat' support for it. however like the docs say, this should work for IE9.

Answer (score 2):

### A similar layout without using CSS tables

You can achieve the same layout without a wrapper element using block level elements:

```
<div id=a>
    <div id=b>B</div>
    <div id=c>C</div>
</div>

#a {
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    left: 40px;
    right: 40px;
    bottom: 40px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
#b {
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
    height:40%;
}
#c {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}
```

However, I am not using CSS table display types, which may or may not be strictly required in some cases.

As noted earlier by others, you will need either a wrapper, `calc()` or JavaScript to enable this layout with tables.

This alternative approach may be helpful to others.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/8qpjZ/

Comment: I made a simplified example to explain my problem, but I really need a display:table based layout. +1 for the useful suggestions (for other people) though.

Comment: I appreciate your constraints, and I do think your original solution with the wrapper was the best approach.