# What version of IE doesn't pass the event as argument to listeners?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, event-handling, dom-events

As some old versions of IE didn't provide the event as argument to event listeners, we got used to `(event||window.event)`.

In order to decide whether it can still make some sense to have this in a modern library, I tried to look at what versions were concerned but I couldn't find this information.

So, what's the most recent version of IE that didn't provide the event as argument ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Internet Explorer provides a global object window.event, which
>   references the last event. And before IE9 there are no arguments in
>   the handler.

[Get from](http://javascript.info/tutorial/obtaining-event-object)

Comment: Found somebody with IE8 and tested, that's right : the event is not passed.

Comment: As i check construction onclick="onclickHandler(event);" in IE8 - i got event object. But i think its depends from event type